# How do routers get their external IP address?

Tags: networking, router, ip

How do routers get their external IP address? Is it assigned by a central service? Is it decided by the ISP? I have googled this problem, but have only found how to change my IP address, which is not what I am after.

Comment: If you're talking about a router connected to an ISP, then yes, the ISP ultimately controls which external addresses can be used to contact your  router through its services.

Comment: ISP defines does you must use some definite WAN settings (if so ISP provides these settings, and you must set up your router accordingly) or you must use DHCP (if so then all settings are obtained from ISP's DHCP service).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Very much like how you have a local DHCP server running on your home router to serve IPv4 addresses on your LAN network (typically in the 192.168.1.x subnet), your ISP *also* has a DHCP server running somewhere that your router gets its WAN address from. The IP address range your ISP's DHCP server hands out are public IP addresses that it has purchased or been assigned.

Comment: And there are also ISPs (like mine) that hand out private IPs for their internal network to customers, as they do carrier grade NAT for most customers.

Comment: @dirkt very true! We have unfortunately run out of IPv4 addresses, which leads to "solutions" like that

Comment: @staehle solutions which work quite well for consumers.

Comment: @RonJohn Certainly for most consumers, most of the time

Comment: @BThompson nothing (affordable) works for all people, all the time.

Comment: @RonJohn I said "solutions" in quotes because while it is a solution, double-NAT'ing is not a great one. Switching to IPv6 would be better! (Though I know there are still a lot of v4-only services out there)

Comment: @staehle Lots of things which are "better" ignore the cost of replacing the *Good Enough That Works, Is Installed, And We All Understand* with *Theoretically Better, A Lot More Complicated, Requires Lots Of New Hardware And Software, **Configuring That Software**, And Training*.

Comment: @staehle and **LOTS** of (literally or figuratively) embedded software *can't* be replaced.  And just thinking about all the firewall rules which would have to be rewritten (especially in Enterprises which much follow SOC1, PCI, etc audits for documentation) would be **a nightmare**.

Comment: This is _one particular way_ it can be handled. Mine doesn't get it via DHCP, because I have a static IP. DSL clients will use PPP. Et cetera.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- True! This was a simple question, so I provided the mostly likely answer without being too confusing for the author. But yes, I work for a fiber optic internet equipment company, and our FTTH customers are about 70/30 split between DHCP over ethernet over GPON vs. PPP over GPON. Fiber GPON can be remarkably similar to DSL if the ISP also has DSL services and wants their new fiber network to "work" the same.

Comment: @RonJohn: The free market is already in the process of solving that problem. IPv4 addresses are going to get progressively more and more expensive over the next few years or so. Sooner or later, the cost of continuing to use an IPv4 address will exceed the cost of switching. But I don't think we're really going to see a mass exodus until companies determine that a large enough proportion of their customers are dual-stack to say "screw the people who are still IPv4-only, we can't afford to keep serving them." That's going to take a while yet.

Comment: @Kevin 10/8 has solved the problem.  The company I work for is **all** 10.x.y.z, and the company we have a big outsourcing contract with is all their own 10.x.y.z (plus some legacy routable addresses).

Comment: @RonJohn: I'm referring to routable IPv4 addresses. *Those* will become scarce. Eventually, the cloud providers are going to start saying "We won't give you a public IPv4 address for free."

Comment: @kevin The immenent demise if IP4V is grossly exaggerated - in my country most ISPs still arn't offering IPV6 by default.  Most people tuned out the drum you are beating years ago. (IPv6 adoption will continue to happen, but very slowly because there us no one to force it, and this scarcity works for established players)

Comment: @davidgo: That's the whole point of the free market, you don't have to care. One day, many years in the future, Facebook/Google/some-other-American-company is going to stop being reachable over IPv4 altogether, and at that point your country's ISPs will suddenly have to scramble to roll out IPv6 all at once (or else they'll have to do some ridiculous workaround for that individual site). But that's their lookout, I suppose.

Comment: @kevin Maybe.  Maybe ipv6 will continue to gradually increase market share  - which I think is likely - although I recently read an article from APNIC (the guys in charge of IP allocation in the Asia/Pacific region) arguing it is quite possible IPv6 will just die because of the client-server model the Internet has devolved into.

Comment: @davidgo Most of SEA is already IPv6. Not sure what APNIC is talking about. I'm getting IPv6 address at my router (Malaysia) but for now also getting public IPv4 address as we still haven't run out of the address allocated to our ISPs. IPv6 rollout have been a huge success considering how few people have noticed it. I noticed it about roughly 5 years ago when I could not connect to Google DNS 8.8.8.8 from my 4G phone connection so had to use the IPv6 version 2001:4860:4860::8888

Comment: @slebetman See the section "the bigger picture on ipv6 transition" at https://blog.apnic.net/2021/02/08/ipv6-in-2020/

Answer (score 14):

There is no single answer to this  save to say that ISP's provide IP addresses out of blocks they own.  A non-exclusive way as to how they may be implementing this -

If the connection used PPPoE or PPPoA the PPP session will have an IP address associated with it. Very commonly these IP addresses will be configured in a Radius server (often backed by a database). The ultimate assignment could be based on userid, come from an IP pool or a characteristic associated with the connection.

In a simple ethernet case an IP address could be assigned statically or via DHCP - although this is not a great way to do things unless there are additional controls to prevent people "stealing" others IP addresses.

Comment: Our ISP uses DHCP with "option 82" via both ADSL and GPON. Their DHCP server always issues the same address for a given physical line ID.

Comment: Controls to prevent 'stealing' IP addresses (more commonly known as spoofing/forging) should always be implemented anyway, as part of network ingress filtering ([RFC 2827](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2827), BCP 38).

Answer (score 4):

Have to agree with you, quite difficult to find a straight answer via google. To me that means it's a good question!

Reason why answering this question is difficult, like Davidgo mentioned, is because there is no single answer. What he probably means is that there is more than one single method or process that leads to assignment of an IP address to a machine. Which method or process is used depends on specific circumstances like e.g. is the router connected to the internet or is it connecting to a(-nother) private network.

Try to keep in mind that all methods, protocols, policies, processes etc. that are required to enable communication are part of a logical, systematic and strict set of rules (so a structure) to ensures unique identification for all connecting machines. If the uniqueness fails, then communication drops out and no networking is possible. So in that sense this full set of rules is the correct answer to your question but that's just a bit too much to take in at once.

Here is a start [A short guide to IP addressing...](https://www.internetsociety.org/resource-library/?tx_resource_types=deploy360) from the [Internet Society](https://www.internetsociety.org/)

Intro below (there is much much more on their site as I just found out.

IP addresses are managed by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA), which has overall responsibility for the Internet Protocol (IP) address pool, and by the Regional Internet Registries (RIRs) to which IANA distributes large blocks of addresses.

The RIRs manage, distribute, and publicly register IP addresses and related Internet number resources, such as Autonomous System Numbers (ASN) and reverse Domain Name System (DNS ) delegations within their respective regions.

They do this according to policies which are developed within their respective regional communities, through open and bottom-up processes.

Answer (score 4):

Routers get their addresses the same way any other device does, which is to say: it depends. It *might* be DHCP (very common in cable and fiber scenarios). It might be IPCP as part of a PPPoE session (common for DSL and some other fiber providers). It might simply be statically assigned and manually configured (common within network providers themselves and for particularly large customers). It might be something completely different. There's no one definitive answer on Google because there's no one definitive answer.